# Build with custom-react-scripts library causes memory leaks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, memory-leaks, mobx, custom-react-scripts

I have a project which works with [custom-react-scripts](https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts) and I faced with memory leaks during development. The application is developed using React, Mobx, Mobx-State-Tree and uses decorators with babel.

When i start development server with command `react-scripts start` 2-3 node.js instances are started:

[image]

And when i'm changing some code in the project custom-react-scripts rebuilds project and more node.js instances appears:

[image]

Few moments after that all memory are allocated with node.js instances and my laptop starts freezing.

Does anyone know how to prevent custom-react-scripts to start new nodejs instances and solve this memory leak issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is hiding in your .env configuration file.
I was facing this issue too earlier and these steps helped me:

1. Remove all semicolons in your .env file.
2. Turn off webpack dashboard by adding: REACT_APP_WEBPACK_DASHBOARD = false

Look at this screenshot *(correct .env config)*. Hope it will help.

[image]